# How do you show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2 + n} = \log\left({32}\right) - 4$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

how to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2 + n} = \log\left({32}\right) - 4$$? Can I use the Alternating Series test and how?

Comment: The alternating series test only allows you to determine whether the series converges or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_1= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2 + n}$$
$$\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2 + n} = \dfrac{3-\frac{1}{n}}{n + 1} = \left(\frac{4}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}\right)$$
So
\begin{align}
S_1 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(\frac{4}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}\right)\\
 &= 4\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{n+1}}_{s_2} - \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{n}}_{-\ln(2)}
\end{align}
We know, then
$$\ln(1 + x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k} = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^2}{3} - \frac{x^2}{4} + \cdots$$
and for $x = 1$ we have
$$\ln(1 + 1) = \ln(2) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1^k}{k} = 1 \underbrace{- \frac{1^2}{2} + \frac{1^2}{3} - \frac{1^2}{4} + \cdots}_{s_2} = 1- s_2$$

Which implies
$$s_2 = \ln(2) -1$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
S_1 &= 4(s_2) - (-\ln(2))\\
&= 4(\ln(2) -1) - (-\ln(2))\\
&= 4\ln(2) -4 + \ln(2)\\
&= 5\ln(2) -4\\
&= \ln(32) -4\\
\end{align}

See:

[the sum: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}=\ln(2)$ using Riemann Integral and other methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167155/the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-1n1-frac1n-ln2-using-riemann-integral)

Answer (score 5):

$$\dfrac{3n-1}{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{3(n+1)-4}{n(n+1)}=\dfrac3n-4\left(\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{n+1}\right)=\dfrac4{n+1}-\dfrac1n$$

This can also be achieved by [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)  $$\dfrac{3n-1}{n(n+1)}=\dfrac An+\dfrac B{n+1}$$

Now $\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}r$ for $-1\le x<1$  by

[What is the correct radius of convergence for $\ln(1+x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$(-1)^{n}\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2 + n} =(-1)^{n}\frac1n\dfrac{3n+3-4}{n + 1} =3\frac{(-1)^{n}}n-4(-1)^{n}\dfrac{1}{n(n + 1)}=\ldots$$

and since by telescoping

$$\dfrac{1}{n(n + 1)}=\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1}$$

we obtain

$$-\frac{(-1)^{n}}n+4\dfrac{(-1)^{-1}}{n + 1}$$

then recall that by [**alternating harmonic series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test)

- $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}n=\ln 2$

Comment: What is the next step?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I was thinking to use the alternating harmonic series for the first term and telescoping for the second one.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I've added some detail more, it should be sufficient now as a hint I think.

Comment: -1 for posting a poor answer, and only in response to a comment, improving it after posting, rather than before submitting it in the first place (not to mention you supplement your post with work from another answer).

Comment: @amWhy I agree that maybe my forst hint wasn't to much cryptically formulated at first but my aim was to let some work to the asker. Of course I would at lest give a reference to the alternating harmonic series which is necessary to conclude the derivation according to my suggestion.

Comment: @amWhy Often we say: "do not give full solution" but I see that some times we say: "not enought hint was given for the solution". Belive me it is not a simple task to satisfy all the requests!

Comment: @amWhy In particular when the question are not properly posted and the asker has not shown completely his effort a small hint is tha best answer we can give. Duplicates, complete answers and comments with complete answers are the worst thing to do for the benefit of the community since that stimulate
the proliferation of such kind of questions.

Comment: @amWhy Errata corrige for my first comment to you: "I agree that maybe my first hint was to much cryptically formulated..."