# What is the limit of the sum of "last half" part of harmonic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, limits

I'm looking for the limit of this sum: $\frac{1}{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil+1}+\frac{1}{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil+2}+\frac{1}{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ when $n \rightarrow +\infty$. 
I guess the limit exists. But I don't know how to find it out. It seems that the formula $-\ln(1-x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n}+\cdots$ doesn't help. May I have some help?

Comment: This is related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n), and may be a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165657/show-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn-ln2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial sum is $H_n-H_{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}$, where $H_n$ is the $n^{\rm{th}}$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)  Since $H_n \approx \log n + \gamma,$ this will approach  $\log n - \log {\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}=\log 2$

Comment: I see, the result should be $\ln 2$, right?

Comment: @Connor:  yes, I dropped a sign.  A $\LaTeX$ hint:  if you put a backslash before ln, you get the right font, so \ln instead of ln gives $\ln$ instead of $ln$