# Convergence of sequence and corresponding series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$a_n$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n)(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}+....+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}$ this sequence can be written as $$a_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}$$
Now, the $nth$ term of this sequence is a sequence of patial sums of the corresponding series( I think this assumption is wrong because the sum varies over $n$ to $2n-1$ (not starting from $n=1$)) .I can think of two ways to check the convergence

**1st** We can write $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} =\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}-\frac{n}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$ and

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}} =\frac{n+2}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}-\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2 )}}$$... Similarly
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}} =\frac{2n}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}-\frac{(2n-1)}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}$$
So, $$a_n =\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)}}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\sqrt{(n)}}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{\sqrt{(n+2)}}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)}}{\sqrt{n+2}}+...\frac{\sqrt{(2n)}}{\sqrt{2n-1}}-\frac{\sqrt{(2n-1)}}{\sqrt{n+n}}$$
When $\lim_{n\to∞}$
$$a_n=(1-1)+(1-1)+.... +(1-1)$$ so $\lim_{n\to∞}$ is zero.

**2nd** (I have doubt in this) can we use series comparison test here?

Take $$u_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}$$ & $$v_n= 1/n$$
$$\lim_{n\to\inf}=u_n/v_n=1\text{(finite & non zero)}$$

Hence $\sum{u_n}$ and $\sum{v_n}$ behaves alike , since $\sum (1/n)$ is Divergent,so $\sum{u_n}$ is. Since I have already mentioned that the summation starts varies from $n$ (not from 1) , is this reason is okay or can someone provide a better explanation for this ?

Comment: First approach is not true because adding property of limit operation is true only for finite number of terms, here number of terms also goes to infinity. Simpler example is $1 = n\cdot\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ as every term goes to $0$

Comment: Egor is right, the first method is incorrect because the number of terms in the series tends to infinity. The second method is also incorrect because the comparison tests start from $k=$ constant, not $k=f(n).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Khostrotash has already showed that $a_n$ is bounded below by $\frac{1}{2}.$

All that is left to show is that $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence, and then by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), we will have proved that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ converges. To show that $(a_n)$ is decreasing means to show that $a_n \geq a_{n+1},\ $ i.e. $a_n - a_{n+1}\geq 0.$ We have:

$$ a_n - a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}$$

$$ = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} + \require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}} } + \ldots + \require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}} } \right)$$

$$ - \left( \require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}} } + \ldots + \require{cancel}\cancel{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}} } + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n)(2n+1)}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}} \right) $$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} - \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n)(2n+1)}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}} \right). $$

We want to show this is $\geq 0,$ i.e.

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n)(2n+1)}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}} \tag{1}\label{eq1}. $$

Squaring the RHS gives:

$$ \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n)(2n+1)}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$

$$ + 2\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right) \sqrt{ \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) \left( \frac{1}{2n+2}\right) } $$

$$ \leq \frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} + \require{cancel}\cancel{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right) \frac{ \left( \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+2} \right)}{\require{cancel}\cancel{2}}\quad \text{ (AM-GM)} $$

$$ = 2\left(  \frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \right) $$

$$ = 2\left(  \frac{1}{(2n)} - \require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{(2n+1)} } + \require{cancel}\cancel{ \frac{1}{(2n+1)} } - \frac{1}{(2n+2)} \right) = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}. $$

---

Alternative approach, which I'll write without rigour for brevity's sake, but it should still convince those familiar with results of harmonic series. For those unfamiliar, then [see this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165657/show-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn-ln2) for example.

From

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(k+1)}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k\cdot k}}, $$

it is not too hard to use the result in the link above and the Squeeze theorem and show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \ln 2.$

Comment: I was trying to do so but getting stuck at the last step that when $\lim_{n \to inf}$ both sides of the expression approaches $0$. But now clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n)(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}+....+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}} \\ \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}+....+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}\\=n\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}
\\ \ge n\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n)(2n)}}\\=\frac{n}{\sqrt{(2n)^2}}=\frac 12$$

Comment: This doesn't show that $a_n$ converges: it only shows that $a_n$ tends to something $\geq 1/2.$

Comment: I meant, it only shows $(a_n)$ is bounded below by $1/2.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson: It was a hint to the first approach.

Comment: @Khosrotash yes ,thankyou ✨